# Continuity, removable and essential discontinuity

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

I want to know if the following 2 functions are continuous or not.

1.
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1/x{^2}  & \text{if } x \ne 0 \\
2 & \text{ if } x=0  \\
\end{cases}.
$$
 Then I want to check the continuity at $0$,
 $$
\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\infty, \quad f(0)=2.
$$
Since $f(0)$ is not equal to $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$,  $f$ is not continuous at $0$.

Since $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ exists (going to infinity doesn't mean that limit doesn't exist right?) and $f$ is not continuous at $0$, isn't this a removable discontinuity?

Because if limit at that point exists and f is not continuous at that point it is a removable discontinuity and otherwise it is essential discontinuity.

2) 
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x^2  & \text{if } x \ne 2 \\
4 & \text{ if } x=2  \\
\end{cases}.
$$
Clearly this is continuous at $x=2$. Isn't it? But the lecturer said this is a removable discontinuity. Isn't he making a mistake here?

Comment: Yes, the second function is continuous. I'm pretty sure you're right.  Usually when people refer to the existence of a limit they are talking about the existence of a finite limit.  Letting $f(0)=\infty$ in the first example would **not** make it a continuous function.

Comment: The first function does *not* have a removable discontinuity. When we write $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=\infty$, what we are saying is that the limit of $f$ as $x\to 0$ does not exist, and we are describing the specific way in which that limit fails to exist.

Comment: I thought we say the limit  does not exist when left and right limit does not equal one another.But here both left and right limit approaches infinity.So that's why I thought the limit exists.So does a **limit approaches infinity** and the term **limit does not exist** are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So does a **limit approaches infinity** and the term **limit does not exist** are the same.

Limits do not approach anything. Functions do. When a function approaches something, we say that its limit is equal to that thing.

Anyway, the terms are not equivalent. The limit $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin (1/x)$ does not exist, but it would not be correct to say that this function approaches infinity; it clearly does not.

However, it is true that when a function approaches infinity, the limit (understood in the strict sense of a limit in $\mathbb R$) does not exist. The failure of limit to exist in this particular way is recorded as "$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty$", a shorthand for "limit does not exist due to $f$ approaching infinity".

Yet, there are ways in which one can extend the definition of  limit to make $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty$ an actual   limit rather than a shorthand form of the statement quoted above. This is a matter of how a particular book / professor define things.

---

Concerning the second part: you are right that $$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x^2  & \text{if } x \ne 2 \\
4 & \text{if } x=2  \\
\end{cases}$$
is a continuous function. It is the same function as "$f(x)=x^2$ for all $x$", only written differently.

Perhaps  what the lecturer had in mind was that 
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x^2  & \text{if } x \ne 2 \\
\text{undefined} & \text{if } x=2  \\
\end{cases}$$
has a removable discontinuity, which is demonstrated by the fact that defining $f(2)=4$ makes a continuous function.